# How can i limit use of enum values in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

Can I somehow limit the usage of incoming enum with kotlin language features?
I have an enum, for example

```
enum class Message {
    NORMAL,
    URGENT,
    LETHAL
}
```

When i get an incoming dto, i need to assure that it contains only URGENT or LETHAL enum values. I'm a bit lazy to write a validator, so could anyone advice some kotlin magick for that case?

Comment: please share some incoming dto code, and the usage you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `require` assertion:

```
val message = Message.NORMAL
require(message in listOf(URGENT, LETHAL)) { "Message must be either urgent or lethal" }
```